# Can you use "PM" for "pro memoria"?

Tags: abbreviations

As the heading suggests, I'm wondering whether the abbreviation "PM" can be used for "pro memoria". I've looked it up in a number of dictionaries, but none of them list 'pro memoria' as a possible meaning of "PM".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* listed at [Abbreviations.com](https://www.abbreviations.com/PM) along with 212 *other* meanings, including Private Message, Prime Minister, Project Manager and many more of varying usefulness. (The abbreviation of Post Meridian is usually written in lower-case letters.)

The [Guardian Style Guide](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a) says,

> If an abbreviation or acronym is to be used more than once in a piece,
> put it in brackets at first mention.

So perhaps you should write "Pro Memoria (PM)" on its first appearance.

Answer (score 2):

PM isn't included in this list of Latin abbreviations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations

However, p.m. does appear in these examples:

https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/pro+memoria.html
https://support.getrodeo.io/en/articles/4824955-how-do-you-use-a-pro-memoria-pm-item-on-a-estimate
https://www.wordsense.eu/p._m./

Some of the Linguee sentences first introduce it with an explanation, which makes sense to do.

> the proposal specifies p.m. (pro memoria).

Answer (score 0):

I found the acronym in ReversoContext; one of the usage examples provided is the following: "A token entry (p.m.) is proposed for commitment and payment appropriations as well as revenue at this time.".
PM means pro memoria according to the site abbreviation.com.